What Package/Algorithm should I use to classify the pixels of a pigs eye in an infrared picture of a pig?
Im a college student working on a project that involves identifying eye features in infrared pictures of pigs so that we can apply a FEM mesh to it and do computations (we haven't created the mesh yet, but I think it will be a single mesh we will apply to all pig photos). I have around a year of experience with python and little experience with machine learning.
I am not sure what to start learning about so I can accomplish this task. I have asked chat GPT to get some background and it seems like I should do semantic segmentation and use Tensor Flow with U-Net. Is this a good suggestion?
Are there already models that I can use that I can just train?
I have a few months to complete this project, and I would like to avoid unnesasarially high amounts of labor in training the model, as I will be doing classes in the fall.
Im looking for a place to start learning, links to information you found helpful are appreciated.
